# RSpec controller example param with periods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my controller spec, when I execute the line:

```
  post :register_pass, :device_id => 'DEV1C3', :pass_type_id => 'pass.com.example.GSPassType', :serial_no => '5ER14L'
```

I get an `ActionController::RoutingError`:

```
  Failure/Error: post :register_pass, :device_id => 'DEV1C3', :pass_type_id => 'pass.com.example.GSPassType', :serial_no => '5ER14L'
  ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:action=>"register_pass", :controller=>"purchases/passbook/registrations", :pass_type_id=>"pass.com.example.GSPassType", :serial_no=>"5ER14L", :device_id=>"DEV1C3"}
```

Even though `rake routes | grep register_pass` returns

```
register_pass POST   /v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_no(.:format)        {:action=>"register_pass", :controller=>"purchases/passbook/registrations"}
```

However, when I remove the periods in the `:pass_type_id` value, the `post` line listed above executes and the route is recognized (I verified this using rspec, and even curled it directly, putting a breakpoint in the expected controller action, the route works).

I tried using `Rack::Utils.escape` on the value with periods, but that failed too. I also tried manually changing the periods to their URL-encoded values, but rails didn't seem to decode them in the params hash.

Why don't periods work in this case?

And how can I get a value with periods passed in (without manually decoding it using `String#gsub` in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems you're encountering: 1) a period is a valid character in a URL sequence, so it's won't be replaced by `Rack::Utils.escape` or `URI.escape`, 2) Rails treats a period as a path separator to enable format parsing at the end of urls, e.g. .json, .xml, etc. (as defined in `ActionController::Routing::SEPARATORS`).

For this use case, I'd recommend adding constraints to this route that allow you to be permissive of any character for `:post_id`. I don't see what your route file looks like, but it could be something like this with the change:

```
post "/v1/devices/:device_id/registrations/:pass_type_id/:serial_no(.:format)" => 
  "purchases/passbook/registrations#register_pass", 
  :constraints => { :pass_type_id => /.*/ }
```

Lots of great info on other ways to add this constraint in the [Rails guide on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: I added the constraints to my routes.rb file, but that didn't seem to help, is some part of rails intercepting this before the constraints are applied?